# Are there best practices regarding card details horizontal or vertical layout?

Tags: design-patterns, ux-field, cards, product-details

What are the best practices for having a product card laid out horizontally or vertically? Can a product card be laid out both ways? If so, my concern is breaking user's mental map of how they're reading the product cards.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcHZ0l.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Are you talking about presenting both horizontal and vertical cards in the same row/column?

Answer (score 2):

I would say it primarily depends on **screen size** and **orientation**.

These factors affect the amount of space available to convey information and ideally you can convey a single piece of information in one line. Imagine you have a long product name; if you are using a horizontal layout on a large screen, the name will likely fit in a single line. However, if you are using a vertical layout, the information may be split into multiple lines. **This is bad because your pieces of information information are no longer split up by verticality**.

The best approach would be to use one layout or the other for consistency's sake. Consider your platform and the amount of information you will be conveying and make a choice based on that.